# Can we use promise in js blocks or .js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, dataform, google-dataform

*N.B: This post duplicate [the issue 1547 @ dataform-co/dataform](https://github.com/dataform-co/dataform/issues/1547)
*
Hi,

We are migrating code to dataform and we need to:

- Make a call to bigquery API to get a list of columns
- Use list of column to replace within a SQL query template
- Execute the SQL query

## Question

Is it possible to use such async logics where we need to interact with external async API ?

We tried two alternatives:

### Attempt 1: Using promise in a js block within .sqlx file

#### Code

```
config {
    type: "table",
    disabled: false,
    hasOutput: true,
    description: "This table contains sales orders",
    tags: ["dedup_test"]
}

js {
   const common = require("our_custom_lib");
   const deduplicationRequest = new common.deduplication.DeduplicationRequest(someRequestParameters...);

   async function output() {
       return await dedup.getDeduplicationRequest(deduplicationRequest)
   }
}

${output().then(res => res)}
```

#### Output

```
Compiling...

Compiled successfully.

Running...

Operation failed:  dataform.dedup_test
  > 
  > 
  > 
  > 
  > [object Promise]
  bigquery error: Syntax error
```

### Attempt 2: Using promise in .js file

#### Code

```
const common = require("our_custom_lib");

const params = {
    database: "our_database",
    schema: "dataform",
    type: "table",
    disabled: false,
    description: "This table contains sales orders",
    tags: ["dedup_test"]
}

async function executeQuery(params) {
    (async () => {
            const deduplicationRequest = new common.deduplication.DeduplicationRequest(someRequestParameters...)
             // Our async logic using bigquery JS client
            return await common.deduplication.getDeltaDeduplicationQuery(deduplicationRequest)
        }
    ).then( dedupQuery => {
            // dataform-core
            publish("transactions",params).query(dedupQuery);
        }
    )
}

executeQuery(params);
```

#### Output

Compilation runs fine but the table does not appear in compiled tables.